# Setting points for an object in pinax-points

Tags: django, pinax

I want to set points or upvote or downvote for an object using pinax-points
But there is no documentation.

I'm adding docs but I'm unable to figure out how to add upvotes or downvotes.

I can get the points using this documentation I have added, but can't set them

```
{% load pinax_points_tags %}

{% points_for_object user as points %}

<div class="user-points">{{ points }}</div>
```

There were also no installation docs.

I followed the following steps for installation.

```
pip install pinax-points

Added pinax.points to installed apps
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **award_points** to add points to any model. This is found in the readme of the project:

```
award_points(model, points)
```

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-points/blob/master/README.md